# Java class path error: ./filename.jar: cannot execute binary file

Tags: java

I got following issue when execute a java class with specified classpaths.
I search Google many times for the solution but it still don't take effect.
Please give me a help, thanks.
Here is description of the problem:

When I run this command on Window:

```
$ java -classpath appfeature.jar;args4j2.0.6.jar mava.AppClassifier class
```

AppClassifier just print out string "HelloWorld" to the standard output. But I got the following result :

```
 $ java -classpath appfeature.jar;args4j2.0.6.jar mava.AppClassifier
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for m
ore details.
./args4j2.0.6.jar: ./args4j2.0.6.jar: cannot execute binary file
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your `mava.AppClassifier` present in a `.jar file`?

Comment: yes. It's ok with this: $ java -classpath appfeature.jar mava.AppClassifier
but fail when add one more additional jar file in classpath.

Comment: You say this is on windows, not unix or linux? How are you running this command?

Comment: @Kenster I run it on cmd.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having similar issues and coming to this page, you should have a comma (,) between your jars, not a semi-colon (;), so the command should be:

```
$ java -classpath appfeature.jar,args4j2.0.6.jar mava.AppClassifier class
```